# How to get a std::iostream from a file by opening it with share locking on Windows?

Tags: iostream

I am looking for a simple solution to open a file, probably using CreateFile and being sure that nobody can read/write to it and still being able to obtain a `std::iostream` object, which is needed later.

Comment: How do you make sure that nobody else can read/write it?

Comment: This seems to be in the right direction http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/cpp/threads/119979/file-and-iostream

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do the following:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

fstream my_stream;
my_stream.open("my.file", std::ios_base::in | std::ios_base::out, _SH_DENYRW);

my_stream << "test";
```

Comment: That's not possible. `std::basic_fstream<...>` does not take a third parameter.

Comment: @0x499602D2 Microsoft's implementation does (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4dx08bh4.aspx) which was the topic of this question

Comment: Okay never knew that. Cool. :)